# Identity records deleted from first table from second table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table A like this:

```
Ordernumber    PartId
--------------------------
10134          6
10134          7
```

Table B:

```
OrderId  OrderNumber PartId Startdate enddate
---------------------------
1        10134        6      4/5/2019  null
1        10134        8      4/5/2019  null
```

I want to identify new part id that got inserted into the Table A and insert those new part id into Table B.

I want to identify old part id that got deleted in Table A and finalize those records in Table B and do other things in the related tables.

So end result should be:

Table B:

```
OrderId  OrderNumber PartId Startdate enddate
---------------------------
1        10134        6      4/5/2019  null
1        10134        8      4/5/2019  7/25/2019
1        10134        7      7/25/2019  null
```

Comment: OK, well what have you tried?

Comment: Why `7/25/2019` as the date, if you mean `current date - 1`, what's your DBMS?

Comment: sql server is the dbms

Comment: I tried, to split the two into two cte, new ones and deleted ones and handle them separately

Comment: Date is just when it gets inserted, its the default date

Comment: There will be few ways to implement this functionality. Either through SQL query that runs every now and then and does the cleanup/adds the record or use **SQL triggers** on **TableA** to do the job for you in Table B and other subsequent tables.  I would go today SQL triggers which will make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 parts:

1. First check for those that where added to tableA and insert them into tableB.

```
    insert into tableB (OrderId,OrderNumber,PartId,startDate)
    select a.OrderId,a.OrderNumber,a.PartId,getdate() as startDate
    from tableA as a
    where not exists (select 1 from tableB as b where a.OrderId = b.OrderId and a.OrderNumber = b.OrderNumber and a.PartId = b.PartId)
```

2. Then check for those that were removed from tableB and update the enddate

```
    update b
    set b.enddate = getdate()
    from tableB as b
    where not exists (select 1 from tableA as a 
                      where a.OrderId = b.OrderId and a.OrderNumber = b.OrderNumber and a.PartId = b.PartId)
```